# Connecting the drain hose of a clothes washing machine to a wider drain pipe

Tags: water, drain, washing-machine

I need to install a clothes washing machine in the bathroom and I have a problem to solve.

The drain hose of the washing machine is 25 mm in diameter on the exterior, made from a soft rubber material - see image A, while the drain is 32 mm in diameter internally made from hard plastic - see image B.

[image]

How do I connect them? Is there some piece that goes in between I can buy? Do I need to cut the head of the drain hose and replace it with something else?

Comment: If you find the machine won't full after you finally find a connector, put an anti siphon connector in line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of time to figure this out I eventually went to a specialized shop and this is what I've got back from there:

[image]

The drain hose of the washing machine goes into the black gasket. The gasket is made of a soft rubber, slitely smaller on the inside diameter and with a pattern on the inside to hold the end of the hose with no glue.

Then the black gasket slitely larger on the outer diameter gets forced into the one end of the large pipe while the smaller pipe goes into the drain. No glue needed there either since the drain has a conic gasket holding the pipe in place.

Still need to install all of this, but it should work :)

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

32mm equals 1.25" USA. Standard 1.25" drain pieces can be obtained at any hardware,Home Depot, Walmart, etc. You could buy another 1-1/4" desanco fitting x 1-1/2" abs or pvc piping. Use the 2 desanco pieces with their washers and jamb nuts back to back and convert to a stand pipe with the 1-1/2" abs or pvc and dump the washing machine drain hose into the stand pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If that drain is not being used for anything else (i.e. you're not connecting a sink on here as well), the normal thing to do would be to buy a "washing machine standpipe", such as is sold at any DIY store (e.g. [this from screwfix](http://www.screwfix.com/p/floplast-washing-machine-trap-white-40mm/18640)). Once that's connected to your drainage, you just stick your machine drain hose into the vertical pipe (using the rigid grey U-shaped bit around the hose, at the top of the pipe; the rigidity stops the hose from coming out of the pipe).

The standpipe usually has a compression fitting on the end of a U-bend; you'd need a short section of pipe to connect from that compression fitting to the push-fit connection you have in your wall. To make matters more complicated, that product I found is in 40mm (which I think is standard), so you'd need a reducer... but I believe flow should only ever go into bigger pipes, not smaller ones. So you'd either need to find one in 32mm, or just make one yourself out of 32mm pipe and a 32mm U-bend.